# Mesos DCOS Spark with different role

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

I installed Spark service on Mesosphere with the following json config.
I was hoping that Spark will use role slave_public.

```
{
    "service": {
        "name": "my-spark",
        "role": "slave_public"
    }
}
```

**dcos package install --options=my-spark.json spark**

But I see in /var/log/message that role * is being used and offers are rejected. Marathon UI show the framework in "waiting" state.

Is it possible to override default role?